# XAML Image tags showing on Android but not iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this image tag in my XAML, as part of a ViewCell data template:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding imageName}" 
VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

I use this line of code to set the bindings, including the image name:

```
messages.Add(new MessageModel { 
    title = "Stappen",
    information = "3240", 
    additionalInfo = "Doel: 5000 stappen per dag",
    messageTime = DateTime.Now, 
    pageToOpen = new ActivityPage(),
    imageName="yellowwarningsmall.jpg" });
```

My file structure has the Android images appearing in PregnancyMobile.Droid/Resources/drawable/ and it works, the images show up in Android. On iOS I have the images, plus upscaled versions for retina, in PregnancyMobile.iOS/Resources.  The images there are yellowwarningsmall.jpg, yellowwarningsmall@2x.jpg and yellowwarningsmall@3x.jpg. All of the iOS image build actions are BundleResource.

Now, on iOS the images don't actually show up. I should note that my testing environment is the iOS simulator, as I don't have a physical iPhone to test with.  Everything else in the iOS app renders as it should, except for the images. Am I missing something?

Output log: http://pastebin.com/mUZRnNV0

Comment: could you share the log from Application Output/Output windows?

Comment: Is your image in Resources folder?

Comment: @Enrico Yes it is.

Comment: is the image name exactly the same on file system to avoid case sensitive?

Comment: Maybe it's not related with but did you check "_Resource: PregnancyMobile.Views.HomePage.xaml... Has XamlCompilationAttribute set to Skip and not Compile... skipped_"?

Comment: If you post your sample code we can try to reproduce

Comment: Have you tried to remove the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Som thanks to [@BrunoeCaceiro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459105/xaml-image-tags-showing-on-android-but-not-ios#comment68186544_40459105) I figured it out.  Apparently, despite all the examples on the internet having the file extension in the image source, you should only put the name, without the extension.

So

```
messages.Add(new MessageModel { title = "Stappen", information = "3240", 
additionalInfo = "Doel: 5000 stappen per dag", messageTime = DateTime.Now, 
pageToOpen = new ActivityPage(), imageName="yellowwarningsmall.jpg" });
```

Becomes

```
messages.Add(new MessageModel { title = "Stappen", information = "3240", 
additionalInfo = "Doel: 5000 stappen per dag", messageTime = DateTime.Now, 
pageToOpen = new ActivityPage(), imageName="yellowwarningsmall" });
```